# Equivalent criterion for a sequence to be Benford

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Take a sequence $\{b_n\} $ of positive integers and define $x_n := \log_{10} b_n \bmod 1$. Furthermore, set $I_k := [\log_{10}(k), \log_{10}(k + 1))$.
> Show that $\{ b_n \}$ is Benford if and only if
> $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N \chi_{I_k}(x_n) = \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{I_{k}}(x) \, dx.$$

I've been stuck on this for quite some time now and can't seem to have any idea. Any hints are appreciated.

The definition for a Benford sequence that I am given is the following. A sequence $\{ b_n \}$ of positive integers is Benford if for each $k \in \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 9 \}$ we have

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\#(\{ n = 1, \ldots, N : b_{n} \text{ has leading digit } k \})}{N} = \log_{10} \Big( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \Big ) > 0. $$

I've already shown that a positive integer $b$ has leading digit $k$ if and only if $\log_{10} b \bmod 1 \in I_k$. So we can write the part in a Benford sequence as saying that $b_n$ has leading digit $k$ when $\log_{10} b_n \bmod 1 \in I_k$.

Comment: The definition of $f$ is missing in the first center display.

Comment: That is how the problem is stated. But perhaps it means the characterstic function $\chi_{I_{k}}(x)$. Either that or any Riemann-integrable function $f$ on $[0, 1]$. But since we are also given the definition of equidistribution, I think it means the characteristic function since it is also on the LHS.

Comment: If it means the characteristic function, I think the RHS should be stated as $|I_k|$, the measure of $I_k$.

Comment: Thanks. I think now it seems more reasonable.

Comment: Under the integral, it should be $\int_0^1$, not $\int_{|I_k|}$. Or, you can just write $|I_k|$ without integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence is standard.
We have
$$
b_n \textrm{ has }k\textrm{ as the first digit} \Longleftrightarrow k\cdot10^s\leq b_n<(k+1)\cdot 10^s \ \textrm{for some }s\geq 0
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow s+\log_{10}k \leq \log_{10}b_n<s+\log_{10}(k+1)
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \log_{10}k\leq \log_{10}b_n \textrm{ mod }1<\log_{10}(k+1)
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \log_{10} b_n \textrm{ mod }1\in I_k. 
$$

Then the equivalence follows. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^N \chi_{I_k} (x_n)$ is the number of $n\leq N$ such that $x_n\in I_k$. Thus,
$$
\frac{\#(\{ n = 1, \ldots, N : b_{n} \text{ has leading digit } k \})}{N} =\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N \chi_{I_k}(x_n) 
$$

Comment: Well yes. That was something I already established. But how does that show that the sequence is Benford $\iff$ the limit of the sum equals the integral?

Comment: Is the integral of the characteristic function simply just the measure of the interval $I_{k}$, which in turn is the same as the limit of the sum, i.e. the sum now counts the set of leading digits in $I_{k}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.